# Proving simulation with rejection generates conditional distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, rejection-sampling

I'm working with Poisson processes, but the idea is more general. I want to simulate a two-dimensional Poisson process (over the unit square so we can ignore an area factor) with parameter $\lambda,$ conditional on the points having minimum separation distance $m.$ To generate a realization of this process, I sample $n\sim$ Poisson($\lambda$), then proceed as follows:

1. Generate $x_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $y_1\sim U(0,1)$.
2. Let $i=2.$ Generate $x_i\sim U(0,1)$ and $y_i\sim U(0,1).$ If $$\min_{j\in\{1,\dots,i-1\}} d((x_i,y_i),(x_j,y_j)) < m,$$ reject $(x_i,y_i)$. Otherwise, keep it.
3. Repeat step 2 until the minimum distance of point $i$ from all previously generated points is at least $m$.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 with $i=3,...,n.$

I was not entirely certain that this algorithm is correct, so I wanted to prove to myself that this is a Poisson process conditional on all points being at least $m$ apart from each other. I tried to bend the proof for rejection sampling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Theory; https://jblevins.org/notes/accept-reject) but could not make it work. How would one prove this?

Comment: You should first write the density of the distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an, that's what I was trying to do. The goal was to write something like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Spatial_Poisson_point_process: $P(N(B) = n) = \frac{(\lambda |B|)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda |B|},$ but now we have $P(N(B) = n \mid \text{minimum separation distance } > m),$ so I don't understand how to continue.